# Как задать такие стили для слайдера

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

У меня есть слайдер с фотографиями.

Один слайд привязан к другому через конфигурацию `asNavFor: 'связанный блок',`

Есть две стрелочки на два слайда.Никак не могу изменить внешний вид активного слайда таким образом как на картинке посмотрите на оранжевые круглые фото .Чтобы в активном слайде был `border` и `scale` также `opacity` ну вот все перепробовал но не смог найти

ссылка на [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/mKyJXr)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.top_slider').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      //              centerMode: true,
      speed:800,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slide_employers',
      //              centerPadding: '220px',
      arrows: true,
      prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev slick-arrow" aria-label="Previous" role="button" style="display: block;">Previous</button>',
      nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next slick-arrow" aria-label="Next" role="button" style="display: block;">Next</button>'
        
    });
    
  });

  $('.slide_employers').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite:true,
    
    });
```

```css
.about_us {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.about_us .our_team_title {
  font-family: "montserrat";
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
.about_us .our_team_title span {
  color: orange;
}
.about_us p {
  font-family: "montserrat";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #999999;
}
.about_us .slide_employers {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
}
.about_us .slide_employers .employer_icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.slide img {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
.slide h2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.slick-center img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
  border: 6px solid #ffb338;
  transform: scale(1.08);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="about_us">
  <h1 class="our_team_title">Our <span>Team</span></h1>
  <p>We are a small team of designers and developers from San Francisco.</p>
  <div class="slide_employers">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5a0983ca1b00004800376c2f.jpeg?cache=limsr63nzp&ops=crop_183_429_1526_1234,scalefit_720_noupscale" alt="Bill Gates">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://24smi.org/public/media/2017/7/6/cristiano-ronaldo-the-best-fifa-football-awards-09012017_kduocf9mtdj1gonxjzdhwsj9.jpg" alt="Warren Buffet">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg" alt="Tim Cook">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg" alt="Satya Nadella">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg" alt="Sundar">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg" alt="Sundar">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg" alt="Tim Cook">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5a0983ca1b00004800376c2f.jpeg?cache=limsr63nzp&ops=crop_183_429_1526_1234,scalefit_720_noupscale" alt="Satya Nadella">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/5a0983ca1b00004800376c2f.jpeg?cache=limsr63nzp&ops=crop_183_429_1526_1234,scalefit_720_noupscale" alt="Sundar">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--eNw_2EtI--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/19engrmo05c5qpng.png" alt="Sundar">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--eNw_2EtI--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/19engrmo05c5qpng.png" alt="Sundar">
    <img class="employer_icon" src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--eNw_2EtI--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/19engrmo05c5qpng.png" alt="Sundar">
  </div>
  <section class="top_slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/250">
      <h2>text 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250">
      <h2>text 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/250">
      <h2>text 3</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img.slick-active {border:5px solid red;}
img.slick-current {
  border:5px solid orange;
  transform:scale(1.5);
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Если добавить стили, все прекрасно работает. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: да у меня не получалось никак спасибо